# Divide Loop Execution According to Threads In Java

Tags: java, multithreading

suppose i have a method **run** as following,

```
public void run()
{  
for(i=loopstart;i<loopend;i++){  
     //some code here to execute. no dependency exists   
}
```

**loopstart & loopend** variables have the min and max value of loop execution.

now what i have to do is to divide this loop execution in 2 to 5 threads in order to execute in parallel. to accomplish this, i have changed this method as

```
public void run()
{
for(i=thread_start; i<thread_end; i++)
     //some code here to execute.    
}
```

the variables **thread_start** and **thread_end** are the ranges each thread has to run. so how it would be best to divide loop execution. suppose i have the loop execution in the range

```
 5-94
```

and i want to divide it to many ranges for execution depending on number of threads.
e.g.

```
 threads               ranges    
 2                     5-44, 45-94   
 3                     5-34, 35-65, 66-94
```

these are just examples (not exact). i want to divide its execution on the basis of threads available.
so for **2 threads**,

```
 thread_start=5  ,thread_end=44       1st thread 
 thread_start=45 ,thread_end=94       2nd thread.
```

how should (using java code)  i divide loop execution in almost same length ranges?

Comment: I strongly recommend that you look at OpenMP for Java - see for example https://www2.cs.fau.de/EN/research/JavaOpenMP/index.html . This will give code that is really quite optimized.

Comment: @adeel iqbal Read about Thread pool with fixed no of threads; and add the tasks in the queue.

Comment: just compute `thread_start[k]=loopstart+looprange*k`, where `looprange=(loopend-loopstart)/number_of _threads`. Make sure looprange>0.

Comment: @Floris the link seems to be useful. thanks, let me take a loop at it first

Comment: @AlexeiKaigorodov how to calculate thread_end. because it is the main issue for me when executing the last thread. how to judge end of loop

Comment: http://programmingexamples.wikidot.com/threadpoolexecutor

Comment: Make your run block as Runnable object and pass it to  threadpoolexecutor. No Divide(loopstart & loopend) rule is required.

Comment: `thread_end[k]=loopstart+looprange*(k+1)-1` except for the last, which equals to `loopend`.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Looper implements Runnable {

    private int start;
    private int end;

    public Looper(int start, int end){
        this.start = start;
        this.end = end;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for(int i=start; i<end; i++){
            System.out.println("thread id : " + Thread.currentThread().getId() + "; index : " + i) ;
        }
    }
}

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Thread looper1 = new Thread(new Looper(1,1000));
        Thread looper2 = new Thread (new Looper(1001,2000));
        looper1.start();
        looper2.start();
    }
}
```

this is what you need? If you need to get available Threads at runtime, you might consider using ThreadPool.

Comment: the issue is how to find the ranges like 1-1000, 1001-2000

Comment: that depends on how do you create those Threads and how many threads you create to carry out the loop.